# JQuery Dialog Modal not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a dialog that should not allow the user to click any elements on the page behind it. I am import the jquery script, and my code looks like this

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    maxWidth: $width * 0.8,
    maxHeight: $height * 0.8,
    width: $width * 0.8,
    height: $height * 0.8
});
```

The dialog does show up, and the user is able to click other elements.

Comment: can you reproduce this issue in a jsfiddle or something? Also, do you have an element with id `dialog` ?

Comment: It's your `$width` and `$height` variables, if you replace them with real numbers it works.

Comment: @karthikr I do have an element with that id. Like I said, everything is functioning properly except for the modular part.

Comment: @SteveWellens Using regular numbers doesn't do it.

Comment: @CodyHarness - Sorry, I misread the problem.   Here's a jsFiddle that works:  http://jsfiddle.net/k9ov3n7w/1/  Note the external resources, jQuery uses CSS to disable the form.

Comment: There is no external resource.